# Control Brushless Motor with Pyboard and ESC

Tags: robotics, micropython

I can't figure this out at all and the docs don't really do any services to a new micropythoner. How does one output to the esc to power the motor?
Here's an example of what I'm trying to do. As you can see I should only need the battery, pyboard, and esc. https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=385

I've got my battery connected to the esc properly. I've tried pyb.Pin(x, pin.OUT).
My pyboard wont import machine.PWM so that option is out (unless someone knows how to remedy that)
I've tried the servo continuous method.

Does anyone know how to implement Timer.PWM() ?
I'm using Putty as my REPL, competently.

Thoughts? This should be pretty easy now that I have everything set up. Everyone is using PIs or Arduino.

Comment: Hi Soren, since that thread is from 2016 my guess is they gave up. BUT, I suggest you ping them there and ask them if any source code is available.